# Converting from image to Pdf and then sending it as response without saving in disk java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to convert the image to pdf and then sending it back as response without saving getting trouble. Below is the code snippet.

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
float width = bimg.getWidth();
float height = bimg.getHeight();
PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
document.addPage(page);
PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(sourceFile.getPath(), document);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
contentStream.close();
 in.close();       
 document.close();
 PDPage documentPage = document.getPage(0);
 InputStream pdfStream = documentPage.getContents();
 byte[] pdfData = new byte[pdfStream.available()];
 pdfStream.read(pdfData); 
 return Response.ok((Object) document).build();
```

Comment: What's the trouble? Please provide stacktraces or further explanations.

Comment: Indeed, you should provide more info as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Hello Matias, a good text would have been that the returned byte sequence can't be displayed as a PDF. (And indeed, that isn't a PDF at all, that is a page content stream).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using ByteArrayOutputStream  are doing it wrong way below is the code snippet. I have edit this so it will be helpful for others as well this is how i am converting image to PDF using pdf box.Below is the working code

```
        @GET
@Path("/endpoint/{resourceName}")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response downloadPdfFile(@PathParam("resourceName") String res) throws IOException {
    File sourceFile = new File("directoryPath/"+ res+ ".png");
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return Response.status(400).entity("resource not exist").build();
    }
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
        float width = bimg.getWidth();
        float height = bimg.getHeight();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
        document.addPage(page);
        PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(sourceFile.getPath(), 
        document);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        contentStream.close();
        in.close();
        document.save(outputStream);
        document.close();
        return Response.ok(outputStream.toByteArray()).build();
```

Comment: @Matias please press the checkmark to make it the accepted answer. Consider also editing the question as explained in the question comments (explain that what you got couldn't be displayed / wasn't a PDF), this way your question will help others too.